# Java signing files with BouncyCastle - Create signature of a file using secret keyring

Tags: java, bouncycastle, pgp

I'm trying to write a Java program that signs a file with a private key. The program takes 3 arguments - file, secret keyring and a password. The output should be in a detached file *.bpg. The problem is that I get the following errors when I try to compile my code:

```
C:\CNS3\BCastle>javac Sign.java
Note: Sign.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

My code is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.bouncycastle.bcpg.*;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.*;

public class Sign {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    FileInputStream keyIn = new FileInputStream(args[1]);
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(args[0] + ".bpg");
    InputStream in = PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(keyIn);
    PGPSecretKeyRingCollection pgpSec = 
                               new PGPSecretKeyRingCollection(in);
    PGPSecretKey key = null;
    Iterator rIt = pgpSec.getKeyRings();
    while (key == null && rIt.hasNext()) {
      PGPSecretKeyRing kRing = (PGPSecretKeyRing)rIt.next();
      Iterator kIt = kRing.getSecretKeys();
      while ( key == null && kIt.hasNext() ) {
        PGPSecretKey k = (PGPSecretKey)kIt.next();
        if ( k.isSigningKey() ) { key = k; }
      }
    }
    if (key == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't find key");
    }
    PGPPrivateKey pgpPrivKey = 
         key.extractPrivateKey(args[2].toCharArray(), "BC");
    PGPSignatureGenerator sGen = new PGPSignatureGenerator(
         key.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm(), PGPUtil.SHA1, "BC");
    sGen.initSign(PGPSignature.BINARY_DOCUMENT, pgpPrivKey);
    PGPCompressedDataGenerator cGen = new PGPCompressedDataGenerator(
         PGPCompressedDataGenerator.ZLIB);
    BCPGOutputStream bOut = new BCPGOutputStream(cGen.open(out));
    FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
    int ch = 0;
    while ( (ch = fIn.read()) >= 0 ) { sGen.update((byte)ch); }
    sGen.generate().encode(bOut);
    cGen.close();
    out.close();
  }
}
```

The errors come from the following lines:

```
    PGPPrivateKey pgpPrivKey = 
         key.extractPrivateKey(args[2].toCharArray(), "BC");
    PGPSignatureGenerator sGen = new PGPSignatureGenerator(
         key.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm(), PGPUtil.SHA1, "BC");
    sGen.initSign(PGPSignature.BINARY_DOCUMENT, pgpPrivKey);
```

Anyone have any suggestion on how I might fix this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the messages mentioned are not errors. They are warnings. Your program will run fine, but the methods or classes you use are marked as deprecated. That means you can still use them, but it is not recommended to do so, because in future versions of bouncy castle, these methods or classes might be removed.

Go to an up to date API documentation of these classes. There should be information what to use instead of the deprecated methods/classes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really got confused with the deprecated methods and I did not realise that the code would work. Thank you @Daniel !